# Padding and margin won't work in Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

So I've started writing my first code to learn bootstrap and margin + padding won't work. I've tried to search for answers but none of them helped. As you can see in the code below. I'm trying to use `m-5` or `p-5` class for my button and the margin and padding won't work and the button stays the same.

I've tried using `pt-5` or `mt-5` so selecting the exact sides I want to expand but these won't work either. I've also experimented with it outside the  section and it doesn't work on any element of the page. I've also tried many different browsers, all ended the same.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container bg-success">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1 class="text-capitalize text-danger">The first boostrap document.</h1>
            <p class="text-dark">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-5">BTN primary</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the button to expand with written padding but it stays the same with padding or margin.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Those are Bootstrap 4 classes, and you're referencing Bootstrap 3. Change your Bootstrap CSS path to: `https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: I knew it will be something dumb like version thanks, mate! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p-5` is a Bootstrap 4 class, yet you've referenced the Bootstrap 3 CSS (and JavaScript) files. If you update this to Bootstrap 4 (making sure to include PopperJS), then your padding will work as expected:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container bg-success">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1 class="text-capitalize text-danger">The first boostrap document.</h1>
        <p class="text-dark">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-5">BTN primary</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```